# Fstab mounting fails at boot, but succeeds when invoked manually

Tags: debian, fsck, fstab, automount

### Background

On our development/backup server at my company we have 4 drives which are setup using software Raid 1, like this:

- Raid 1 (system disk): 2 x 320 GB
- Raid 1 (store/backup disk): 2 x 2 TB

Forming 2 "virtual" disks.

Now some people at the office want to migrate some data from an 1 TB drive from an old server. So what I've done is that I have a docking station for the disk which is connected to our server through USB. Now I've added that drive to `fstab` using it's `UUID`.

### The problem

The problem is that the drive fails during boot:

```
fsck.ext3: Unable to resolve 'UUID=36c78260-3c5d-4746-9759-682797e12609'
fsck died with exit status 8
```

Surely there is something I have missed. Also it would be nice not being forced to set checking to 0.

### Troubleshooting I have done so far

1) Trying to mount the drive from `fstab` manually:

```
mount -a
```

Works fine without errors

2) Running `fsck` on the drive manually:

```
root@overlord:/var/log/fsck# fsck -t ext3 /dev/sde1 
fsck from util-linux-ng 2.17.2
e2fsck 1.41.12 (17-May-2010)
/dev/sde1: clean, 195327/61054976 files, 240677045/244190000 blocks
```

### Additional information

`fstab` file:

```
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
proc            /proc           proc    defaults        0       0
UUID=17239a5a-4dc4-459a-8cee-2a44c4070d0a /               ext3    errors=remount-ro 0       1
UUID=07c02b0a-c98e-4858-8acb-bc7b9e8bfec7 /mnt/store      ext3    defaults        0       2
UUID=36c78260-3c5d-4746-9759-682797e12609 /mnt/backup     ext3    defaults    0   2
```

`blkid` output:

```
/dev/sda1: UUID="78dc058d-d6d9-ff3f-4ff1-526ea2d9ea75" LABEL="overlord:0" TYPE="linux_raid_member" 
/dev/sdb1: UUID="78dc058d-d6d9-ff3f-4ff1-526ea2d9ea75" LABEL="overlord:0" TYPE="linux_raid_member" 
/dev/sdc1: UUID="c17a04c7-79f9-b140-dcbc-2adbe4e2b483" LABEL="overlord:1" TYPE="linux_raid_member" 
/dev/sdd1: UUID="c17a04c7-79f9-b140-dcbc-2adbe4e2b483" LABEL="overlord:1" TYPE="linux_raid_member" 
/dev/md0: UUID="17239a5a-4dc4-459a-8cee-2a44c4070d0a" TYPE="ext3" 
/dev/md1: UUID="07c02b0a-c98e-4858-8acb-bc7b9e8bfec7" SEC_TYPE="ext2" TYPE="ext3" 
/dev/sde1: UUID="36c78260-3c5d-4746-9759-682797e12609" SEC_TYPE="ext2" TYPE="ext3"
```

`by-uuid` output:

```
root@overlord:/# ls -la /dev/disk/by-uuid/
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 100 Jul 25 22:06 .
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root 100 Jul 25 22:06 ..
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   9 Jul 25 22:06 07c02b0a-c98e-4858-8acb-bc7b9e8bfec7 -> ../../md1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   9 Jul 25 22:06 17239a5a-4dc4-459a-8cee-2a44c4070d0a -> ../../md0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  10 Jul 25 22:06 36c78260-3c5d-4746-9759-682797e12609 -> ../../sde1
```

Comment: Can you check to see if vol_id -u /dev/sde1 returns the same UUID as blkid does?

Comment: Debian doesn't seem to have the `vol_id` command. Never the less, the disk mounts fine when invoked manually. Shouldn't that mean we can rule out that it would be the wrong UUID? I have added the output of `/dev/disk/by-uuid` in my question, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I immediately thought that the USB drivers for the device, or whatnot, aren't getting loaded before fstab is "executed." So after googling "mounting usb drive fstab" I found this: http://solutionsandtips.blogspot.com/2009/05/uuid-fstab-and-automatically-mount-usb.html

Comment: Thank you for the link. And your theory about usb not going loaded before `fstab` sounds really reasonable! I tried adding the udev rule but it never executes the command. So for now I have just put the `mount` command in the `/etc/rc.local`. Which works, but it feels like a nasty hack.